# Alarm Manager doesn't work on time

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have this method which should schedule alarms but when the time arrives it doesn't start the pendingintent ??

```
public void setAlarm(String name, long time) {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent dialog = new Intent(this, SubActivity.class);
    dialog.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, dialog, 0);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() < time) {
            am.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, time, pi);
        }else{
            time+=(AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*7);
            am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pi);
        }
    } else {
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, time, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pi);
    }
}
```

Comment: **1** - `setExact()` won't work prior to API Level 19. **2** - `setRepeating()` is **inexact** starting from API Level 19. **3** - Your code should be pasted **here**, not on `pastebin`.

Comment: okay ..
i check the code i've checked the SDK version before if it was >= 19 i used setExact and setRepeating for versions less than 19 i tested it on loli pop devices and on device API 16 but it doesn't work on both :/

Comment: `setExact()` only works on API 19+. Use `set()` for lower versions.

Comment: i told you i have tested it on device its API 19+ and it doesn;t work also

Comment: This parameter: `String name` is **never used**. Your code has **other bugs**, as stated above... please check it out carefully. Also please show `how do you call this method` in your current code.

Comment: but will be used later but first i want the code run first that't he important part and its inside service 
i startService first i read the alarms from sqlite table and then loop through them and set them one by one i have cheked the loges its goes inside set code part but it doesn't fire the alarm on time and never

Comment: `i read the alarms from sqlite table and then loop through them and set them one by one` So you have **more than 1 alarm**. But their PendingIntent id is always **0**: `PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, dialog, 0);`. Therefore, the latest one you set replaces the previous one/s.

Comment: ah thank you bro for that by the way i have tried broadcastreciver and now its works very well on API +19 also on less than 19 :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using a `PendingIntent` for an `Activity`, which will not necessarily keep the device awake long enough for the `Activity` to get started.  You'll have to use a `PendingIntent` for a `BroadcastReceiver` which leverages a wake lock to keep the device awake until your app code can run.  [`WakefulBrodcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) is a good choice, or you can roll your own as needed.  See this article for an explanation and sample of how to use alarms to wake the device: http://po.st/7UpipA

Comment: No problem!  I'm glad you were able to get past it!